# PHP5.5 OPCache Messages - Message Cached script

Tags: php, opcache

Just upgraded VPS to PHP 5.5 and now when the magento cron.php script runs, my cron daemon is sending me an email with the following messages (before it didn't send me any messages at all):

```
Thu May 21 14:30:01 2015 (4542): Message Cached script '/home/#####/public_html/cron.php'

Thu May 21 14:30:01 2015 (4542): Message Cached script '/home/#####/public_html/app/Mage.php'

Thu May 21 14:30:01 2015 (4542): Message Added key '/home/#####/public_html:app/Mage.php:/home/#####/public_html:A'

Thu May 21 14:30:01 2015 (4542): Message Cached script '/home/#####/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php'

Thu May 21 14:30:01 2015 (4542): Message Cached script '/home/#####/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php'

Thu May 21 14:30:01 2015 (4542): Message Cached script '/home/#####/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php'

Thu May 21 14:30:01 2015 (4542): Message Added key '/home/#####/public_html:Mage/Core/Model/App.php:/home/#####/public_html/lib/Varien:B'

Thu May 21 14:30:01 2015 (4542): Message Cached script '/home/#####/public_html/lib/Varien/Event/Collection.php'
```

The jobs still seem to run, so I don't think it's actually stopping anything. But I'm not sure why I'm now getting these messages?

Do you think they are bad?

How can I stop them?

Comment: What's the value of `opcache.log_verbosity_level` in your script?

Comment: Hi Zerkms... thanks for the good pointer!! I've just double checked my php.ini and the verbosity level is 3... that's probably what the issue is!! I've commented out the verbosity level line and have restarted apache... *fingers crossed* this works!

Comment: Another note: apache and cli php may use different php.ini files.

Comment: How do I find the cli php php.ini file?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Zerkms for the pointer!
Looks like I had opcache.log_verbosity_level set to 3 in my php.ini - DOH!
So I just commented that line and now everything seems fine.